# Excel VBA Write formula to a cell, refering to a number dependent on I and a sheet also dependent on I

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, text, formula

Could someone give me some pointers on how to write this formula right?

```
Sub WriteFormulaTextAndNumbersDependentOnI()
Dim xNumber As Integer
xNumber = InputBox ("Choose I")
    For I = 1 To xNumber
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1 + I).Formula = "= & 2,10 + 0,01 * (I - 1)'" & Sheets(I + 1).Name & "'!B12"
    Next I
End Sub
```

The point here is to write a name in different cells, with a calculated number (2.10 + 0.01*(I - 1)) and text from another sheet:

Lets say we have in Sheet2:
B12 = Hello World

Lets say we have in Sheet3:
B12 = You are cool!

We should then get in Sheet1:
I = 1 would give a value/text in cell B2, with the value/text: "2.10+0.01*(1-1) B12" = "2.10 Hello World"
I = 2 would give a value/text in cell C2, with the value/text: "2.10+0.01*(2-1) B12" = "2.11 You are cool!"
An so on.

Any suggestions?

Appreciate any suggestions

//GingerBoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

- `Concatenate()` worksheet function to mix numbers and text in the same string
- `Text()` worksheet function to format a number to a string

as follows:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1 + I).Formula = "=concatenate(TEXT(2.10 + 0.01*(" & I & "-1),""0.00""), "" "", " & Sheets(I + 1).Name & "!B12)"
```

see that:

- I used `Cells(2, 1 + I)` to write in in B2, C2 ... as per your narrative
- I used dots (`.`) as decimal separator: you may want to change all dots into commas as per your decimal separator conventions

Comment: Thanks DisplayName! :)
After some Juggling around, I ended up with this line of code working perfect from me, based on your good points! 

`code`       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 41 + (I - 1) * 8).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(TEXT(2,""0""), ""."", TEXT(1,""0""), ""."", TEXT(1 + 1*(" & I & "-1),""0""), "" "", ""Construction"", "" "", TEXT(1 + 1*(" & I & "-1),""0""), "":"", "" "", '" & Sheets(I + 1).Name & "'!B4)"           `code`

Thanks alot, and have a great week! ^^